# I am having trouble getting 3 strings from the user using cin.getline() and using a pointer array to store them

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I am getting an exception thrown at my cin.getline. I am new to c++, I am sorry if the code is really bad.

The GetInput function should do the following:
This function accepts three lines of user-input text and stores the entered lines as three individual strings.  Use a pointer array to store the strings.  The function should ask the user to enter in three lines of data.  The function will store the information in the pointer array.  (cin.getline()).  Should be allocated in inside GetInput and should be exactly the correct size for each string.

```
int main() {
    char* str[2];
    GetInput(str); 

}

void GetInput(char* ptr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Enter a string: ";
        cin.getline(ptr[i], strlen(ptr[i]), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: What memory does `char* str[2];` point to?

Comment: Nowhere at the moment right?

Comment: Correct.  So when you try to copy data into what it points to?

Comment: Yep. And there are only two of them.

Comment: Doesnt it start at 0, making it three? 0, 1, 2?

Comment: @Jolly_Jimmy I'd recommend you should look into the standard c++ features `std::string` and `std::vector` (or `std::array`).

Comment: Not sure where exactly it should be pointing, I am struggling with pointers.

Comment: Starts at 0 and has a total of two elements for 0, 1

Comment: you probably want a `std::vector<std::string>` instead

Comment: most struggle with pointers can be avoided completely by just not using pointers when you dont need to, i can tell you, after many years you will still struggle with them..

Comment: It is a requirement for an assignment or else i would not be using pointers

Comment: what exactly is the requirement? Please add it to the question, because to get 3 strings from the user you dont need a single pointer

Comment: I added it to the description

Comment: The `strlen` function measures the length of a string. You have no strings anywhere when you first call `strlen`. That can't possibly be right. Can you explain what you think that `strlen` call measures the length of and why you felt you needed to measure the length of something before you got input?

Comment: I have to admit that I dont know how to do it from the top of my head. The teacher is probing skills that you wont need once you left the class. Not using `string` and/or `vector` when you can is rather unrealistic

Comment: I know, this is frustrating me so bad

Comment: I have to have the exact size allocated for each string, I thought it would measure the length of the string entered.

Comment: @Jolly_Jimmy The parameters to a function have to be evaluated before that function can begin executing. So the `strlen` operation must take place before the call to `getline`. If you do `f(1+2);` the addition of `1` and `2` must take place first to produce the 3 that will be passed to `f`. So you're trying to take the length of a string before you have any string.

Comment: How would I get the length though before i call getline?

Comment: @Jolly_Jimmy You can't. You can't possibly know the length of the input until the input is complete. So you will either need to use some input function that allows you to increase the size of the buffer during the input or you'll need to input into a larger buffer and copy into a correctly-sized buffer later. My guess is you are expected to use a large buffer and copy into a dynamically-allocated, right sized buffer after you get the input into the large buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that the assignment demands pointers since this would have been easy using `std::vector<std::string>`. If you do need to use pointers, make use of smart pointers, like `std::unique_ptr`. They will `delete/delete[]` the raw pointer they own when they are destroyed (go out of scope) and will therefor help preventing memory leaks. So, using arrays and pointers, this is one way it could be done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>    // std::array
#include <cstring>  // std::memcpy
#include <memory>   // std::unique_ptr

constexpr size_t max_line_length = 256;

// convenience alias
using CStrPtr = std::unique_ptr<char[]>;

void GetInput(std::array<CStrPtr, 3>& ptrs) {
    char buf[max_line_length]; // temporary buffer when reading a line

    // loop through the 3 pointers in the array
    for(CStrPtr& cptr : ptrs) {
        std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
        std::cin.getline(buf, max_line_length);
        size_t len = std::strlen(buf) + 1; // +1 to make place for the string terminator, '\0'
        // create a new pointer to a char[] with space for the string
        // and assign it to the pointer in the array
        cptr = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);
        // copy the string in buf into the space the raw pointer held by cptr now points to
        std::memcpy(cptr.get(), buf, len);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<CStrPtr, 3> strs;
    GetInput(strs);
    for(const CStrPtr& cptr : strs) {
        std::cout << cptr.get() << "\n";
    }
}
```

In case you're not allowed to use the standard smart pointers, you could create your own smart pointer or a simple string class. Here's a version of the above but with a simple string class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>     // std::array
#include <cstring>   // std::strlen
#include <algorithm> // std::copy

constexpr size_t max_line_length = 256;

class cstring {
    char* m_mem; // the precious pointer
public:
    cstring() : // default constructor
        m_mem(new char[1]) // make place for the string terminator
    {
        m_mem[0] = '\0'; // the string terminator
    }
    cstring(char const* buf) : // converting constructor
        m_mem{}
    {
        // allocate memory
        size_t len = std::strlen(buf) + 1;
        m_mem = new char[len];
        // and copy buf to m_mem
        std::copy(buf, buf+len, m_mem);
    }
    cstring(const cstring& o) : // copy ctor
        cstring(o.m_mem) // delegate to converting ctor
    {}
    cstring(cstring&& o) : // move ctor
        // copy the pointer from o and set o:s pointer to nullptr
        m_mem(std::exchange(o.m_mem, nullptr))
    {}
    cstring& operator=(const cstring& o) { // copy assignment
        *this = cstring(o); // using copy ctor + move assignment
        return *this;
    }
    cstring& operator=(cstring&& o) { // move assignment
        // swap pointers: let o destroy our old pointer for us
        std::swap(m_mem, o.m_mem);
        return *this;
    }
    ~cstring() { delete[] m_mem; } // destructor

    // user-defined conversions
    operator char const* () const { return m_mem; }
    operator char* () { return m_mem; }
};

void GetInput(std::array<cstring, 3>& ptrs) {
    char buf[max_line_length]; // temporary buffer when reading a line

    // loop through the 3 pointers in the array
    for(cstring& cptr : ptrs) {
        std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
        std::cin.getline(buf, max_line_length);
        // create a new cstring and assign it to the cstring in the array
        cptr = cstring(buf);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<cstring, 3> strs;
    GetInput(strs);
    for(const cstring& cptr : strs) {
        // cptr will here use the user-defined conversion to "char const*"
        // for which there's a standard operator<< defined
        std::cout << cptr << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Smart pointers would be nice, but I do not believe they are allowed.

Comment: @Jolly_Jimmy That sounds terrible, but in that case, I'd encapsulate the raw pointer in a string class of my own. Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getLine(string ptr[]) {
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
        string line;
        getline(cin, line);
        ptr[index] = line;
    }
}

int main() {
    string ptr[3];
    getLine(ptr);

    for (int index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
        cout << ptr[index] << endl;
    }
}
```

There were several tings wrong with your code. First, you didn't allocate enough space for your array. Your length should be the length of the array, not the index of the last element. So if it's 3 strings, it's [3].

Next, I wouldn't use char * but instead use the string class. See my code.

Third, your strlen stuff -- well, you have an array of pointers to random places in memory, or maybe an array of null pointers. Either way, it's wrong.

You COULD have done something like this:

```
char myStrings[3][1000];
```

And then in your getline, use 1000 as the maximum length (maybe 999 -- I don't use getline in the form you did). This would allocate 3 character arrays of 1000 bytes each.

But the strlen thing just flat won't work because you don't start with any strings to strlen from.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I cant use the string class for this assignment and in the getline it should allocate exactly what is needed for the string.

Comment: Getline doesn't allocate space. You give it a maximum length of your already-allocated buffer. You could make a very large buffer then use strdup() to copy it into place.